# How to display ROW of Table A from 2 Table?

Tags: mysql

I have a Table A and Table B
Table A (Student)

```
Table A (Student)
ID   |   UserName
01   |   Allan
02   |   Mark
03   |   Rey


Table B (Payment)
ID   |   Amount
01   |   100
01   |   300
02   |   0
03   |   300
```

using `Table Join`, I just want to view row from my Table A without duplicating a display. My condition will be that if we see your payment in Table B. Then we will display record from Table A.

Comment: Try your homework first for yourself. When it does not work, you may get help here.

Comment: In table B "ID" is refer to Table "A"?

Answer (score 0):

On assumption ID is reffering Student Table. 
Below is the query:

```
SELECT Student.UserName as user,COALESCE(SUM(Payment.Amount), 0)   AS TotalPayment
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Payment
ON Student.ID=Orders.Payment.ID
```